How to compose environment variables on conditions Dockerfile
I'm working in enabling the multi-architecture build for a Docker project and I'm facing an issue when I try to alter an environment variable through a condition based on the architecture.
In the dockerfile there is a place, at the end where an environment variable is set:
ENV GROBID_SERVICE_OPTS "-Djava.library.path=grobid-home/lib/lin-64:grobid-home/lib/lin-64/jep --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"

I want to add -Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork to this env variable when the architecture is ARM64.
I tried to check the TARGETARCH:
ARG TARGETARCH
ARG PROCESS_MECHANISM

RUN if [ "$TARGETARCH" = "arm64" ]; then \
        PROCESS_MECHANISM="-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork "; \
    else \
        PROCESS_MECHANISM=""; \
    fi

RUN echo "Selected process spawning mechanism: $PROCESS_MECHANISM"

ENV GROBID_SERVICE_OPTS "$PROCESS_MECHANISM-Djava.library.path=grobid-home/lib/lin-64:grobid-home/lib/lin-64/jep --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"

but the env variable is lost in the process.
The exact point is here and this would include the full Dockerfile.

Not entirely understanding your Dockerfile. TARGETARCH seems to be a build argument for a second stage image. What is its value when you build? Where does it come from? Usually it is copied from a previous image stage but I cant find it in the base image.

the TARGETARCH is set up by the buildx process, in the github action which attempt the multi architecture build for both amd64 and arm64.

You can't set variables like this in the Dockerfile.  (Also see Conditional ENV in Dockerfile.)  What you can do is to fill in the environment variable as part of the container startup sequence.
In your Dockerfile, don't attempt this conditional check.  Set the environment variable to the value without the computed part.  You'll also need to copy in an entrypoint wrapper script, which we'll discuss shortly.
ENV GROBID_SERVICE_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=grobid-home/lib/lin-64:grobid-home/lib/lin-64/jep --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
...
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ...                         # same as you have now

The environment variable will be recomputed and set every time the container starts, but this is a pretty inexpensive operation (especially compared to a JVM startup).  With this recipe you can double-check what's being generated with debugging commands like
docker run --rm your-image sh -c 'echo $GROBID_SERVICE_OPTS'

which will launch a temporary container and run that alternate command (note the single quotes, so the variable expanded by the container shell and not the host shell).  Other debugging commands like docker inspect and docker exec won't run via this entrypoint wrapper and so won't see the environment variable setting, but this frequently isn't a problem.
The entrypoint script checks the processor architecture, maybe extends the environment variable, and then runs the main container command.
#!/bin/sh

# Set the environment variable based on the CPU architecture
if [ "$(uname -m") = arm64 ]; then
  PROCESS_MECHANISM="-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork "
fi
echo "Selected process spawning mechanism: $PROCESS_MECHANISM"
GROBID_SERVICE_OPTS="$PROCESS_MECHANISM$GROBID_SERVICE_OPTS"

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"


I'm wondering if, instead of this approach, to create a .env file with two different content based on the env variable?

You could, but you'd risk using the ARM64 value on x86_64 hardware, and vice versa; doing it in a script pretty much ensures you'll get it right.
